# custom key value pair in fhir json

Tags: hl7-fhir

i have mapped around 20 fields from the sample data. All of them come under Observation category. I have a field/Label which we created to denote each patient.

```
"PatientLabel" : 0
```

I understand FHIR is all about fixed set of items. But, is there a way to include this in FHIR Json. i would need this information while processing.

```
  "extension": [
  {
    "name": "PatientLabel",
    "value": 0
  }
```

tried the above one.. FHIR validator is throwing error

Comment: well, what's the actual error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions don't have a 'name', they have a 'url'.  Also, 'value' is a polymorphic type, so you'd need "valueInteger" or "valueDecimal".  That said, "0" seems an unusual value for something titled "patient label".  Normally, the Patient would be in the Observation.subject.  If you just have a label and not a reference, you could use subject.display and not need an extension at all...

Comment: 0 and 1 denotes whether the person has diabetes or not. Can you please tell me what value should i give in url ? if posible can you post me an example json block for PatientLabel?

Comment: May be the name PatientLabel is misleading.. Imagine it is DiabetesLabel and it can be 0 or 1 for each patient

Comment: That seems like poor modeling. FHIR is intended to make sharing of data more easy and consistent.
Diabetes is a condition and you should create a Condition resource for the patient that has a code indicating diabetes. It should not be a label on an Observation.

Comment: makes sense. i have created it based on resourcetype condition and it has appropriate status too. Thanks